# Що означає "німами" у словосполученні "кричати німами"?

Tags: значення-слів, прислівники

Часто чула в деяких селах на Бойківщині фразу ***"кричати ні́мами"***. Якщо в контексті, то буде так: *"Як я заховаюся десь, а моїй бабі мене сильно треба, то вона так кричить **ні́мами**!"* Коли перепитувала що означає той вислів, то мені відповідали: "Ну та так кричит і всьо!"
Вирішила сьогодні ["загуглити"](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&biw=1317&bih=641&ei=hvprW5TfBcjMwQLYyZfQAw&q=%D1%89%D0%BE+%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%94+%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8&oq=%D1%89%D0%BE+%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%94+%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8&gs_l=psy-ab.3...331613.333002.0.333687.7.7.0.0.0.0.149.872.0j6.6.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.YyG_BgjGlTA), однак такого вислову у просторах Інтернету взагалі немає.

Отож цікавить, що означає слово **ні́мами**?

Comment: Я наголос який?

Comment: @Sasha Наголос все ж таки впливає на розумінньа, а не _јак попало_ буваје, еге? Коли Бојківшчина, то раџу також дивити сусьідньі мови.

Comment: @Sasha, наголос падає на перший склад: нІмами

Comment: Стрів [_нім_](http://slovopedia.org.ua/103/53405/1077585.html) јак _поки_, шчо дльа Буковини. Тому і тут діже невпевнениј.

Comment: [Онишкевич](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/ua/elib.exe?&I21DBN=UKRLIB&P21DBN=UKRLIB&S21STN=1&S21REF=10&S21FMT=fullwebr&C21COM=S&S21CNR=20&S21P01=0&S21P02=0&S21P03=I=&S21STR=-404155) теж не дуже допомагаје.

Comment: @follower, ЕСУМ каже, що _нім_ — це з польської і є в білоруській.

Comment: Можливо запозичення з германських мов? https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/nim

Comment: Цілком може бути!

Comment: Або ж з волапюка

Answer (score 5):

Не знаю, ніколи не чув. Можу лише висловити безпідставні припущення, що це щось пов'язане зі словом «німий». Тобто «кричить німами» = «кричить німа мов» = «кричить мов німа». Як може кричати німа?

Ну, по-перше, під словом *німий* не завжди розуміється той, кто зовсім не може видавати звуки. Частина таких людей мають певні проблеми з голосовим апаратом, слухом тощо, через які їм важко нормально говорити (і вони й не намагаються), але загалом можуть видавати якісь звуки — і коли така людина в разі форс-мажору намагається привернути увагу голосом, це (через невміння керувати голосовим апаратом) може виглядати доволі незвично й навіть лячно для звичайної людини. Тобто «кричиш як німа» у значенні «лячно, нелюдськи кричиш».

По-друге, корінь *-нім-* зараз вживається не лише на позначення нездатності говорити, а й на позначення нечутливості — *занімілий*. Тобто «кричиш мов німа» у значенні «кричиш, наче з тобою щось сталося, наче ти німіти почала».

По-трете, можливе обернення значення слова для якихось конкретних випадків уживання (не знаю, чи має цей процес назву, але таке трапляється).

Також можливі інтерпретації з тим самим «німий», але що воно стосується слухача, а не крикуна (тобто «кричиш німами» як «кричиш, мов я німий», а не «кричиш, мов ти німий»).

Також можу висмоктати з пальця теорії про походження від *нимавідь* (див. у 4-му томі 7-томного етимологічного словника) або якось від *няти/йняти/німати/імати* (з безліччю значень).

Ну або ж *німами* може бути не обставиною (не характеризувати те, як вона кричить), а бути тим, що вона кричить — тобто не «кричить німами», а «кричить: „Німами!“» — де *німами* може бути всім, чим завгодно: від недочутого імені до якогось діалектного вигуку.

Comment: доволі цікаво, дякую!

Comment: @OksankaS., але навряд чи є правдою (бо я коли писав, думав, що наголос на другому складі — _німа́ми_, та й загалом імовірніше не вгадав, ніж угадав).

Comment: але це вже хоч щось! Тому будь-яка думка, навіть помилкова, завжди наближує до правильної відповіді!)

Comment: Дарма прийняли. По-моєму, це все-таки неправильна гіпотеза. Це, звісно, Ваше право, але по-моєму, краще б воно залишалося неприйнятим (сподіваюся, більше уваги привертиме й, може, хтось іншу гіпотезу висловить).

Comment: Але це єдина відповідь наразі і, як на мене, теж має право на життя.